# VB .NET Changing the color of the Buttons

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way for me to minimize the codes below or another way for me to code it?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Red
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use one event handler for all buttons.
`sender` passed to the event handler is the instance of button which were clicked

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow

    DirectCast(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```

Comment: can i also use this way for panels?

Comment: Yes, event handlers are just functions with the signature provided by an event.

Comment: There is an error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel'.' I changed the text "Button" in the directcast to "Panel"